# How to update Firefox when it says already up to date

Tags: macos, firefox, browser

I am using a mac system with firefox version `52.4.1`. I can't update it from `About Firefox` option because it says up to date. But, as I understand there are newer versions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest installer and reinstall it.

Comment: such a simple thing, but somehow didnt cross my mind. Thanks!